# Cruise Control.Net Email Publisher nothing happens

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have been unable to successfully send an email from my project builds.  I have added the following section to the project in the ccnet.config file and nothing happens.  I was hoping for some sort of trace or error messages in the build log assuming something is wrong.

```
<publishers>
  <xmllogger logDir="C:\Build\src\Library\TestLibrary\BuildLogs" />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="5" />
  <email from="sbssatch@test.com" mailhost="mail.corp.test.com" mailport="25" mailhostUsername="batch" mailhostPassword="password" includeDetails="TRUE" useSSL="FALSE">
    <users>
      <user name="Eric Schrama" group="buildmaster" address="eschrama@mail.com"/>
    </users>
    <groups>
      <group name="buildmaster" notifications="always"/>
    </groups>
  </email>
</publishers>
```

Eric

Comment: I managed to get this to email me but I still am wondering if there is a trace if the emaill cannot be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Email errors typically appear in the event viewer on the server.  If the error was recognized by cruise control it would also typically show a failing task in the dashboard, along with a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the smtp server asministrator to get the log.

The error can be catch by CC.NET, resulting in an exception on the dashboard (if smtp if not accessible) but as it is in publish section, the global build will still be **success**.